# How to get a specific name from another array by its id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get the name of the genre by its id from another array? I've tried calling .find on the genres
array but it says undefined

```
 const movies = [ 
  {movieName: blank, id: 1, genre_ids: [5,6,7]}, 
  ...more movies
  ]
const genres = [
       {id:5, name: 'action'}, 
       {id:6, name: 'comedy'},  
       {id:7, name: 'horror'}
 ]


movies.map((movie) => <Movie title={movie.movieName} key={movie.id} genre={???}/>
```

Comment: *How* did you try calling `.find`? Give a [mre].

Comment: Your movies seem to have multiple genres, do you only want to render the first one ? all of them ? What is your component supposed to receive ?

Comment: What do you want in `genre={???}`? Do you want to replace `[5,6,7]` with `['action','comedy','horror']` and pass `genre={['action','comedy','horror']}`

Comment: i used .find like this `  const getGenreById = ({...genreId}) => {
    const genre = genres.find((currGenre) => currGenre.id === genreId.id);
    return genre.name
  };` 
and i want to render all of them but i can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```js
const movies = [ 
  {movieName: 'blank', id: 1, genre_ids: [5,6,7]}, 
  {movieName: 'move 2', id: 2, genre_ids: [5,7]}
  ]
const genres = [
       {id:5, name: 'action'}, 
       {id:6, name: 'comedy'},  
       {id:7, name: 'horror'}
 ]


movies.map((movie) => console.log(
movie.genre_ids.flatMap(g => 
  genres.filter(genre => genre.id === g)
  .map(r => r.name)
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much i had no idea that there's something called .flatMap()